# Delete QueryDef Error 3622 Open SQL Server Table with Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table in SQL Server and a form in Access. I have a query with a parameter to delete a record providing a given ID. In the click event of a button I use a querydef object and try to execute the query and throws this error:

> Error 3622 Open SQL Server Table with Identity Column
>
> You must use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordSet when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column

**The table definition**:

```
CREATE TABLE [Formativa].[SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS](
[ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CODIGO_FAMILIA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[NOMBRE_FAMILIA] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[FECHA_CONTROL] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
```

**The querydef**:

```
PARAMETERS [ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA] Long;
DELETE SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS.ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA, SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS.*
FROM SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS
WHERE (((SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS.ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA)=[ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA]));
```

**The code**:

```
Dim dbCurrDB As DAO.Database
Dim qryDelFamilia As DAO.QueryDef

Dim lngIdFamiliaFormativa As Long

Set dbCurrDB = CurrentDb
Set qryDelFamilia = dbCurrDB.QueryDefs("SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS_ELIMINAR")

With qryDelFamilia

    .Parameters(0) = lngIdFamiliaFormativa
    .Execute
    
    If .RecordsAffected = 0 Then
        mVntMsg = "Ha sucedido un error al eliminar la familia formativa. No es posible proseguir."
        MsgBox mVntMsg, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "ERROR AL ELIMINAR"
        Set dbCurrDB = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End With
```

¿Any idea of what's wrong? I need to use saved queries instead of SQL strings in code because of mantainability, traceability, etc... Also I need to use parameters or equivalent to be able to delete a particular record.

Edit:

I tried with a pass-through query with a variable but I don't know how to establish the value of the variable when I execute the query in vb.

```
DECLARE @ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA Int
BEGIN
DELETE FROM EDIBON_ERP.Formativa.[SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS]
WHERE EDIBON_ERP.[Formativa]. 
[SEPE_FAMILIAS_FORMATIVAS].ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA=@ID_FAMILIA_FORMATIVA
END
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to add the option when executing the query: `.Execute dbSeeChanges`.

Comment: Of course @Kostas K.! Like when opening a recordset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to add the `dbSeeChanges` options when executing the query.

```
.Execute dbSeeChanges
```

It's best to add the `dbFailOnError` option as well, which will rollback changes if the query fails for whatever reason. The option will throw a runtime error though, so you need to have error handing in the method.

```
On Error GoTo Trap

With qryDelFamilia

    .Parameters(0) = lngIdFamiliaFormativa
    .Execute dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges 
    
    If .RecordsAffected = 0 Then
        mVntMsg = "Ha sucedido un error al eliminar la familia formativa. No es posible proseguir."
        MsgBox mVntMsg, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "ERROR AL ELIMINAR"
        Set dbCurrDB = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End With

Leave:
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally forgot that Execute method admited arguments...

Comment: Yeah, I just did it. Thanks again!